# Input text value string validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, text, input

Whenever I click on my button it always says "please enter an email" even though there is text in the box. What am I doing wrong? I see that the ID for the password is incorrect. Right Now Im going to try and put the variables in the function.

```
var emailText = document.getElementById("Email").value;
var emailErrorMessage = document.getElementById("emailError");
var passwordText = document.getElementById("Password").value;
var passwordErrorMessage = document.getElementById("passwrodError");
var button = document.getElementById("submit");

function buttonValidation1(){
    var text;

    if (emailText === "") {
      text = "Please enter an email";
    }else{
      text = "Email OK";
    }

    emailErrorMessage.innerHTML = text;
}

button.addEventListener("click", buttonValidation1);


  <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <head>

        </head>
     <!--<body>
        <p>Please input a number between 1 and 10:</p>

        <input id="numb">

        <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>

         <p id="demo"></p> -->

        <label>Email: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" id="Email"></input><span id="emailError"></span>
        <br/> <br/>

        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="Password"></input>
        <spanid="passwordError"></span>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit"></input>
        <script src="Form.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Add you HTML code please.

Comment: 3 === means boolean comparison, maybe only use 2 if you want to do a string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Move all variable into body function

```js
function buttonValidation1(){
    var emailText = document.getElementById("Email").value;
    var emailErrorMessage = document.getElementById("emailError");
    var passwordText = document.getElementById("Password").value;
    var passwordErrorMessage = document.getElementById("passwrodError");
    var button = document.getElementById("submit");
    
    var text;
    
    if (emailText === "") {
        text = "Please enter an email";
    }
    
    else {
        text = "Email OK";
    }
    
    emailErrorMessage.innerHTML = text;
}

button.addEventListener("click", buttonValidation1);
```

Comment: I think this will fix it, because the emailText will be set when the function is called rather than before it's defined.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. But I dont know what I had to use the three equal signs to get it to work. it was giving me an error when i only used two equal signs and set it equal to "". It would allow me to use two equal signs and

Comment: " " with a space in between the quotes.